# xdebug does not work on localhost

Tags: php, macos, debugging, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have installed xdebug on my MacBook Pro with PHP 5.6.29 and using sublimeXdebug as client (both server and client are on same machine).

It works perfectly fine when I connected to internet and `xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.35`. It is not working when I specify the configuration as `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1` or `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`.

I won't be on internet all the time. And the internet address changes every time I connect to access point. I don't want to go the `php.ini` file to edit the configuration each and every time I connect to internet.

How do I fix this?

My Xdebug configuration in `/etc/php.ini` file is

```
zend_extension= /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
```

Comment: 1) Do you have local web server (Apache/nginx)? 2) If you do -- how they run PHP -- php-fpm perhaps?

Comment: I am using Apache webserver. I didn't get your second question.

Comment: Well .. OK. 1) Please run this command and show the results: `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` -- I need to see who listens on TCP 9000 port 2) Please provide xdebug log (`xdebug.remote_log`) for such successful and not debug sessions.

Comment: have you tried xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1 and remove the xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 setting?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your php.ini:

xdebug.max_nesting_level = 10000

xdebug.remote_autostart = 0

xdebug.remote_enable = 1

xdebug.remote_port = 9000

You can try having xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 instead of 0 above to just try things out and see if it is working.

Comment: I don't know exactly why it isn't working but from looking at the path of your xdebug, you are not using macports (or something like that.) I urge you to look up macports and install all of your stack from there (apache, php, xdebug, mysql, etc...)

Comment: I think it can be solved with some configuration changes, rather than installing the whole stack again.